# Double.ToString не более, чем два знака после запятой

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли с помощью [Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d8ztz0sa.aspx) вывести **не более**, чем два знака после запятой?

```
10.2345 →  "10.23"
10.0    →  "10"
10.20   →  "10.2"
100     →  "100"
```

Если да, то как?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, например так:

```
lCurrentTime.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", ((double)duration)); // тьфу, эт не то
```

Лучше так:

```
string result = duration.ToString("#.##");
```